# Resolve Yahoo Fantasy Football API Internal server error

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api

I wrote a Yahoo fantasy football skill that does things like: get team status, replace injured starters, get weekly matchup, and get leauge standings. It uses OAuth2 and the Yahoo API to get a Yahoo user's leagues and teams. It works great for some accounts, but for some accounts the below request responds with a 500 error.

```
GET https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/users;use_login=1/teams

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error xml:lang="en-us" yahoo:uri="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/users;use_login=1/team"xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" xmlns="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng">
    <description>Server Error</description>
    <detail />
</error>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around using:

```
GET https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/users;use_login=1/games/teams
```

I just have to filter by season.

Comment: Have you had any more issues with getting a 500 Internal Server Error? I've jumped through all the OAuth hoops but when I call the URL above I still get a 500.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ends up here, I ran into this issue and it seems that Yahoo has basically silently deprecated / removed support for oauth, so you have to switch to oauth2 to in order to use many of their APIs.

[Source](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Help-with-Fantasy-Baseball/Receiving-500-quot-Internal-Server-Error-quot-from-Yahoo-Fantasy/m-p/347199/highlight/true#M7680)